# more than one listener for the queue manager

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, mq

Can there more than one listener to a queue manager ? I have used one listener/queue manager combination so far and wonder if this possible. This is because we have 2 applications connecting to same queue manager and seems to have problem with that.

Comment: Unfortunately, the question is far too vague to be answerable definitively.  Instead of saying "*we have 2 applications connecting to same queue manager and seems to have problem with that*" **tell us what the problem is,** in detail, and with evidence such as screen shots, stack traces, log entries, etc. If this were on any of the more popular tags it would have been closed within minutes.  Please see: [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple meanings for the term `listener` in an MQ context.  Let's see if we can clear up some confusion over the terminology and then answer the question as it relates to each.

As defined in the spec, a [JMS listener](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnceq/index.html) is an object that implements a callback mechanism.  It listens on destinations for messages and calls `onMessage` when they arrive.  The destinations may be queues or topics hosted by any JMS-compliant transport provider.

In IBM MQ terms, a `listener` is a process (`runmqlsr`) that handles inbound connection requests on a server.  Although these can handle a variety of protocols, in practice they are almost exclusively TCP listeners that bind a port (1414 by default) and negotiate connection requests on sockets.

**TCP Ports**
Tim's answer applies to the second of these contexts.  MQ can listen for sockets on multiple ports and indeed it is quite common to do so.  Each listener listens on one and only one port.  It may listen on that port across all network  interfaces or can be bound to a specific network interface.  No two listeners can bind to the same combination of interface and port though.

In a B2B context the best practice is to run a dedicated listener for each external business partner to isolate each of their connections across dedicated access paths.  Internally I usually recommend separate ports for QMgr-to-QMgr, app-to-QMgr and interactive user connections.

In that sense it is possible to run multiple listeners on a given QMgr.  Each of those listeners can accept many connections.  Their job is to negotiate the connection then hand the socket off to a Message Channel Agent which talks to the QMgr on behalf of the remotely connected client or QMgr.

**JMS Listeners**
Based on comments, Ulab refers to JMS listeners.  These objects establish a connection to a queue manager and then wait in `GET` mode for new messages arriving on a destination.  On arrival of a message, they call the `onMessage` method which is an asynchronous callback routine.

As to the question "*can there more than one (JMS) listener to a queue manager?*" the answer is definitely yes.  A multi-threaded application can have multiple listeners connected, multiple application instances can connect at the same time, and many thousands of application connections can be handled by a single queue manager with sufficient memory, disk and CPU available.

Of course, each of these applications is ultimately connected to one or more queues so then the question becomes one of whether they can connect to *the same* queue.

- Many listeners can listen on the same queue so long as they do not get exclusive access to it.  Each will receive a portion of the messages arriving.
- Listeners on QMgr-managed subscriptions are exclusively attached to a dynamic queue but multiple instances on the same topic will all receive the same messages.
- If the queue is clustered and there is more than one instance of it multiple listeners will be required to get all the messages since they will normally be distributed by MQ workload distribution across those instances.

Comment: Thanks Rob. so if there are 2 applications (with similar JMS listener configuration) deployed in same JBOSS server, will one of them consume or both get portion of it ?

Comment: Depends on the speed of the messages arriving in relation to how fast they are processed.  When the application issues a `GET` which MQ represents by pushing a handle onto a stack.  The first message goes to the last thing to register a GET.  If that thing completes processing and issues the next GET before a new message arrives, it will get the next message.   If messages arrive faster than they can be processed, they are given to the next thing with a GET handle on the queue.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can create as many listeners as you wish:

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.explorer.doc/e_listener.htm

However, there is no reason why two applications can't connect to the queue manager via the same listener (on the same port). What problem have you run into?

Comment: they both consume the same queue apparently and one times out if other is successful consuming it.

Comment: That shouldn't matter. Are you sure one application isn't consuming all the messages leaving the second application without any messages to consume?

Comment: Typically you would have different applications using different queues. You might have multiple instances of the same application using one queue, but you would expect unrelated applications to use their own queue(s).

Comment: yes I agree. Its a mock consumer application of actual consumer and they both are deployed in same server together caused the problem.

Comment: Ok. So different listeners won't help. They need to be on different queue managers or different queues on the same queue manager.

Comment: User @ulab appears to be talking about a JMS Listener ("consume the same queue") whereas Tim appears to be talking about an MQ listener (sockets on ports).  Ulab can you clarify your question?

Comment: @T.Rob I assumed they are both same but what i mean is JMS listener as I talk from application point of view.